# reference to datetime in powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime, reference

```
$var = "01/01/2020"
$date1 = Get-Date
$date2 = Get-Date
Write-Host $date1.GetType().Name
Write-Host $date2.GetType().Name
$dates = @(
    @('date1', [ref]$date1),
    @('date2', [ref]$date2)
)
foreach($date in $dates) {
    $date[1].Value = Get-Date ([DateTime]::ParseExact($var, 'dd/MM/yyyy', $null)) -Format "dd/MM/yyyy"
}
Write-Host $date1
Write-Host $date2
Write-Host $date1.GetType().Name
Write-Host $date2.GetType().Name
```

output :

```
DateTime
DateTime
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
String
String
```

I do not understand why my dates (date1 and date2) went from DateTime to String ?
How do I fix it ? because the next step in my code is to compare date1 and date2 (I want to compare dates not string obviously)

Help is much appreciate

Comment: You are setting it to a string inside your `foreach`.  Using the `-Format` parameter with `Get-Date` outputs a string, which you are assigning to `$date1`/`$date2`.  Note that using `[ref]$date1` creates a 'reference' or pointer to the original variable (e.g. `$date1`) and _not_ a copy of its value - if you update this reference via your array, it is exactly the same as updating the original variable, hence it becomes a string because that's what you updated it with.

Comment: Thank you I had no idea that the -Format was returning a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem

```
 $date[1].Value = Get-Date ([DateTime]::ParseExact($var, 'dd/MM/yyyy', $null)) -Format "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Remove the `-Format "dd/MM/yyyy"` from your code.

You are parsing a string to a date using `[DateTime]::ParseExact` then immediately convert it back to a string using `-Format "dd/MM/yyyy"`.

You just need

```
$date[1].Value = Get-Date ([DateTime]::ParseExact($var, 'dd/MM/yyyy', $null))
```